# Logitech G933 headset crashes mouse

Tags: usb, sound, mouse, 16.10, logitech

I'm at my wits end here.

I'm on Ubuntu 16.10 x64 and 4.8.0-27-generic

I've been chasing down an issue with my Logitech G930 headset since 16.04 came out. Every time I'd plug in my G930, my keyboard LEDs would flash, and then die. If I plugged in another keyboard, I could see that the USB Device disappeared.

I just bought a New Logitech G933 headset to replace my possibly faulty G930. However, when I plug it in, My mouse now flashes, and dies, along with the G933 headset.

I've tried hardlining the headset, and that doesn't work either.

What logs do I need to start with to help troubleshooting?

I have PulseAudio logging, however, I don't believe it'd directly related to pulseaudio now, and maybe some kind of kernel bug killing my USB Devices.

I've looked at the advice on this blog:

https://hobo.house/2016/01/26/logitech-g933-wireless-headset-linux/

which references this bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xserver-xorg-input-evdev/+bug/1155819

But I cannot get any of the solutions to work? Maybe I'm missing something.

Any help is appreciated...Please and thanks.

I watched my syslog as I selected the headset as my Audio Device:

```
Nov 25 20:06:52 computername kernel: [  230.270366] ohci-pci 0000:00:13.0: HcDoneHead not written back; disabled
Nov 25 20:06:52 computername kernel: [  230.270373] ohci-pci 0000:00:13.0: HC died; cleaning up
Nov 25 20:06:52 computername kernel: [  230.270423] usb 5-1: USB disconnect, device number 2
Nov 25 20:06:52 computername acpid: input device has been disconnected, fd 20
Nov 25 20:06:52 computername kernel: [  230.415884] usb 5-5: USB disconnect, device number 3
Nov 25 20:06:52 computername unity-settings-[2481]: Unable to get default sink
Nov 25 20:06:52 computername acpid: input device has been disconnected, fd 21
Nov 25 20:06:55 computername gnome-software[2854]: failed to get updates: no results to show
Nov 25 20:06:55 computername conky.desktop[2862]: conky: statfs64 '/media/Data': No such file or directory
Nov 25 20:07:01 computername kernel: [  239.701530] logitech-hidpp-device 0003:046D:4024.0008: HID++ 2.0 device connected.
```

Comment: When I search for logitech g33 headset it's corrected to g633, is this correct? `options usbhid quirks=0x046D:0x0A38:0x0004` may work but should be corrected to the actual address of the device as described [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/13035/49853). I'm not sure if the address is 0003:046D:4024.0008 or something else, more than the last 10 lines (e.g. `dmesg | tail -n100`) might help. You should look at https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingProcedures, file a new bug, keep the test case simple and provide all relevant information (I know that it can be difficult).

Comment: A combination of setting the right USB Hardware ID/address AND plugging the device into a USB 3.0 port fixed this. I followed the tutorial of one of the links I posted above, however, I added the (correct) USB Hardware ID to /etc/modprobe.d/usbhid.conf and plugged the G933's receiver into a usb 3.0 port, and have had no issues for 2 days of pretty heavy usage.

Comment: You should answer your question yourself then ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A combination of setting the right USB Hardware ID/address AND plugging the device into a USB 3.0 port fixed this. I followed the tutorial of one of the links I posted above, however, I added the (correct) USB Hardware ID to /etc/modprobe.d/usbhid.conf and plugged the G933's receiver into a usb 3.0 port, and have had no issues for 2 days of pretty heavy usage.

I found correct hardware IDs by using `lsusb`.

```
cat > /etc/modprobe.d/usbhid.conf << EOF
options usbhid quirks=<Hardware ID>
EOF
```